# Consigo acessa site somente pelo ip

Tags: ip, dns

Hospedei uma aplicação na DigitalOcean mas so consigo acessar pelo IP. Mudei os servidores DNS ontem a tarde. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso tenha feito todos os procedimentos de forma correta.

[Time_to_live (TTL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live)

> TTLs também ocorrem no Domain Name System (DNS), onde eles são definidos por um servidor de nomes autoritativo para um registro de recurso específico. Quando um servidor de nomes em cache (recursivo) consulta o servidor de nomes com autoridade para um registro de recurso, ele armazena esse registro em cache pelo tempo (em segundos) especificado pelo TTL. Se um [stub](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stub) resolver consultar o servidor de nomes em cache para o mesmo registro antes que o TTL tenha expirado, o servidor de cache responderá com o registro de recurso já armazenado em cache, em vez de recuperá-lo do servidor de nomes com autoridade novamente. As respostas TTL para NXDOMAIN são definidas a partir do mínimo do campo MÍNIMO do registro SOA e do TTL do próprio SOA e indicam quanto tempo um resolvedor pode armazenar em cache a resposta negativa.
>
> TTLs mais curtos podem causar cargas mais pesadas em um servidor de nomes autoritativo, mas podem ser úteis ao alterar o endereço de serviços críticos como servidores Web ou registros MX e, portanto, freqüentemente são baixados pelo administrador DNS antes de um serviço ser movido, para minimizar interrupções .
>
> As unidades utilizadas são segundos. Um valor mais antigo TTL comum para DNS foi 86400 segundos, que é 24 horas. Um valor TTL de 86400 significaria que, se um registro DNS foi alterado no servidor de nomes autoritativo, os servidores DNS em todo o mundo ainda poderiam estar exibindo o valor antigo de seu cache por até 24 horas após a alteração.